# Submitting a pyspark job to Amazon EMR cluster from terminal

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr, spark-submit

I have SSH-ed into the Amazon EMR server and I want to submit a Spark job ( a simple word count file and a sample.txt are both on the Amazon EMR server ) written in Python from the terminal. How do I do this and what's the syntax?

The word_count.py is as follows:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

from operator import add
import sys
## Constants
APP_NAME = " HelloWorld of Big Data"
##OTHER FUNCTIONS/CLASSES

def main(sc,filename):
   textRDD = sc.textFile(filename)
   words = textRDD.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(' ')).map(lambda x: (x, 1))
   wordcount = words.reduceByKey(add).collect()
   for wc in wordcount:
      print (wc[0],wc[1])

if __name__ == "__main__":

   # Configure Spark
   conf = SparkConf().setAppName(APP_NAME)
   conf = conf.setMaster("local[*]")
   sc   = SparkContext(conf=conf)
   sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId","XXXX")
   sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey","YYYY")
   filename = "s3a://bucket_name/sample.txt"
   # filename = sys.argv[1]
   # Execute Main functionality
   main(sc, filename)
```

Comment: Check this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-submit-step.html. This will allow you submit python spark job [as a step to your emr cluster] via terminal. Else look at this i.e. how to do it using boto3 apis https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706512/how-do-you-automate-pyspark-jobs-on-emr-using-boto3-or-otherwise

Comment: use pyspark shell or spark-submit

Comment: @Snigdhajyoti, I'm aware that I have to use spark-submit. However, I'm confused about the parameters that follow.

Comment: On master node just do a `spark-submit --help` you will find all the parameter that is needed. And if you want to configure spark configs look in [the docs for configs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

Comment: Alright. Also, let's say I want to create a step to submit my job. The "Add Step" option allows me to specify one script to run. So, does that mean that I would need 1 step to execute 1 single .py script? Also, can one add multiple steps? @Snigdhajyoti

Answer (score 1):

You can run this command:

```
spark-submit s3://your_bucket/your_program.py
```

if you need to run the script using python3, you can run this command before spark-submit:

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3.6
```

Remember to save your program in a bucket before *spark-submit*.

Comment: Is it not possible to run the code without storing it in an S3 bucket?

Comment: Also, do I have to create a step if I want to submit a program that's on the S3 bucket?

Comment: No, it's not necessary to create a step. You can just store the program in a bucket and then run spark-submit on EMR terminal. I think this is the easier way to achieve this.

Comment: why is it necessary to have the program in a bucket before doing spark-submit?

Comment: The spark-submit command you suggested is not working for some reason. I used the command on the terminal after SSH-ing into the master node. However, I am getting an EmrFileSystem error. The .py code I want to run is on the S3 bucket.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem not found

Comment: It works without any issue!!