# How do I automate pyspark-submit adding Steps to running EMR Cluster?

Tags: python, pyspark, boto3, amazon-emr

I need to automate pyspark scripts to execute on an existing AWS EMR cluster for a client.  The constraints are:

1. No ssh access to the cluster's head node
2. Can't create any EC2 instances
3. Others in my group add their code to the Steps tab for the running cluster
4. I have read/write access to S3
5. The cluster remains in a running state; no need to script its stand-up or tear-down
6. I have PyCharm pro

I reviewed this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706512/how-do-you-automate-pyspark-jobs-on-emr-using-boto3-or-otherwise), which is close to what I am after.  Ideally, I would use Python with boto3 with PyCharm to pass the PySpark code fragment to their long-running cluster.  What would others do here?

Comment: The answer you linked is using python and boto3. Can you elaborate on what you need different from that answer?

Comment: If you follow the first link in that post, it describes the use of Airflow as part of the workflow and the first step is to stand-up and EC2 instance.  The client is a bank.  I can't even install Firefox on the virtual desktop they provision.